# Why won't RadioSelect buttons appear in my browser when using the relevant widget in Django ModelForms?

Tags: python, django, forms, model

I have been using Django ModelForms in an attempt to display a number of fields as radio buttons. However, after following the guidance in Django Docs regarding the RadioSelect widget, no radio buttons are displaying in the browser. Can anybody explain why?

I have followed the instructions as set out in the Django Docs (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/widgets/#radioselect). The relevant code is detailed below:

#### My ModelForm

```
class ReviewForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Review
        fields = ['subject', 'feedback', 'mentorship', 'hiring', 'community']

class RawReviewForm(forms.Form):
    RATINGS = (
        ('1', '1'),
        ('2', '2'),
        ('3', '3'),
        ('4', '4'),
        ('5', '5'),
    )
    subject = forms.CharField(label='')
    feedback = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
    mentorship = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect(choices=RATINGS))
    hiring = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect(choices=RATINGS))
    community = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect(choices=RATINGS))
```

#### My view

```
def review_create(request):
    review_form = RawReviewForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        review_form = RawReviewForm(request.POST)
        if review_form.is_valid():
            review_form.save()
            Review.objects.create(**review_form.cleaned_data)
            return redirect(reviews)
    context = {
        'form': review_form
    }
    return render(request, 'reviews/review_form.html', context)
```

#### My form template

```
<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <fieldset class="form-group">
        <legend>Leave A Review</legend>
        {{ form.as_p }}
        {% for radio in form.mentorship %}
        <div class="myradio">
            {{ radio }}
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
        {% for radio in form.hiring %}
        <div class="myradio">
            {{ radio }}
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
        {% for radio in form.community %}
        <div class="myradio">
            {{ radio }}
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </fieldset>
    <button class="btn" id="submit" type="submit">Post Review</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/widgets/#widgets-inheriting-from-the-select-widget):

> The choices displayed on the widget are inherited from the `ChoiceField` and changing `ChoiceField.choices` will update `Select.choices`.

So, just pass the choices to the `ChoiceField`:

```
mentorship = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect, choices=RATINGS)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML must be fixed to  `{% for radio in RawReviewForm.mentorship %}` to view data.